# LDAP group has 'member's but the members dont have the 'memberof' attribute

Tags: ldap, alfresco, ldap-query

I am new to LDAP (AD) and I wonder how can I retrieve all users of a group if the users itself doesn't have the "memberof" attribute (which should link to the group I think)?

Following LDAP Structure

```
- Users
   - UserA (memberof=Group1)
   - UserB (memberof=Group1,memberof=Group2)
   - UserN ...
 - Groups
   - Group1 (member=UserA,member=UserB)
   - Group2 (member=UserB)
   - GroupX ...
 - AppGroups
   - App1 (member=UserA,member=UserB)
   - AppX ...
```

So how can I query only the users which are members of `App1` group from `AppGroups` if the users don't have the attributes `memberof` for this group?

I am trying to achive this with Alfresco. Querying the groups is no problem but I can't find a way to also sync the users (and only the users of the group `App1`)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the LDAP server implements the memberOf Attribute?  Not all LDAP server implementations provide MemberOf as an attribute.

Comment: @jeemster yes because users have the memberOf attribute (seen in my structure) and they also can be queried/found using the `memberOf` attribute in the conditions. But they dont have the memberOf attribute for all groups (especially for the group I needed)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either form a query that asks the server to retrieve all users whose `memberof` attribute contains your group's distinguished name, or, you can turn the logic around and ask the server to give you the `member` attribute of the group. The `member` attribute on a group contains all members' distinguished names. You can then obtain additional information about the users by reading the objects one-by-one.

Performance-wise, this is **much** slower, but if there is no `memberof` attribute on the users themselves, this might be the only option for you.

Comment: Okay that's the answer I was looking for. The next challenge for me is building the query but for sure I will talk to our sysadmin why this group is missing in the user's `memberOf` attribute.Thank you random citizen!

Answer (score 1):

The 'memberOf' attribute is supported by the [`memberOf` overlay](http://linux.die.net/man/5/slapo-memberof), *if:*

- you have configured it
- you have modified the memberships of this DN *since* you installed the overlay. It isn't retrospective.

Comment: Thank you for the information. But I am not the sysadmin who manages the ldap so I dont know much about the setup. I can only browse the ldap directories and see the structure seen in my question. So is it generally possible to query the users and check if they are a member of the group `App1`?

Comment: Only under the conditions I have described. Absent that, you have no basis for expecting that the `memberOf` attribute will even exist.

Comment: So I only can check memberships if the `memberOf` overlay is 1. installed/configured and 2. the user has a `memberOf` attribute refering to the group I want to check the membership? There is no other way and I will never be able to check the membership between `UserA` and the group `App1` in the ldap structure in my question?